# RequireJS - Google Maps & Marker Manager Plugin

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, requirejs

I'm working on a site using Require js and I need to implement Google Maps.  I'm also using the [Marker Manager](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html) Google Maps plugin.

I'm using the async Require plugin to load Google Maps api but I'm having a problem with the marker-manager plugin. It's firing before Google Maps Api has loaded (see below).

How can I get marker-manager to wait until Google Maps api has loaded if it loads asynchronously?

Thanks,
Scott

```
define(['marker-manager',
        'async!https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'], 
     function (mm, gapi) {
         // yadda, yadda
         console.log("Finished loading");
     });
```

console output:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
["Finished loading"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to specify callback function in the google maps define statement. Example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async

Reason: Google Maps loads many JS files asynchronously, so listening just to the first script load isn't enough to check.

Another example with google maps callback and requirejs integration:
http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/10/using-jquery-dot-deferred-and-requirejs-to-lazy-load-google-maps-api/
In summary:
- Abstract the google maps API with a wrapper object
- Create a single $.Deferred() object
- Queue up calls on the maps API by wrapping the code inside done()
- Use the async loading option of google maps api with a callback
- In the maps callback, call resolve() on the deferred object